# Sylow's theorems for Symmetric Group and Finite Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

There are several proofs of Sylow's three theorems. Historically, Cauchy first proved that

> *if the order of a symmetric group $S_n$ is $p^aq$ ($p$ is prime, and $q$ is relatively prime to $p$), then $S_n$ has a subgroup of order $p^a$*.

*Using this theorem*, it can be shown every finite group possesses a Sylow-$p$ subgroup ([see this](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=6N2aoMYbYQMC&pg=PA98&dq=Sylow%27s%20theorem%20double%20coset&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6wEwAGoVChMIjLfgyfruyAIVB_djCh1seAXe#v=onepage&q=Sylow%27s%20theorem%20double%20coset&f=false)).

This shows that Sylow's *first* theorem for arbitrary finite group can be deduced from Sylow's first theorem for Symmetric group.

**Question 1.** Are there independent proofs of Sylow's second and third theorems for Symmetric groups, which do not use arguments for general finite group?

**Question 2.** Can we prove Sylow's second and third theorem for arbitrary group with the information that they are being proved for symmetric groups.

Comment: Maybe with linear algebra